# Cakephp different sessions for different users

Tags: session, cakephp

I have cakephp application which has two separate logins one for admin and one for employee. I am using session to store login details.but when i logged out from admin it automatically logouts from employee and vice versa. can i use two different sessions for that?

I am not using role based login. Instead i am using plugin for admin
admin App Controller

```
 $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
                'loginAction' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login',
            ],
                'authenticate' => [
                    'Form' => [
                        'userModel' => 'Users',
                        'fields' => ['username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password']
                    ]
                ],
                'authError' => 'Enter Credentials',
                'storage' => 'Session',
                'unauthorizedRedirect' => false

            ]
        );
```

Employee App controller

```
  $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Employees',
                'action' => 'loginemp'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Employees',
                'action' => 'loginemp',
            ],
            'authError' => 'Enter Credentials',
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'userModel' => 'Employees',
                    'fields' => ['username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password']
                ]
            ],
            'storage' => 'Session',
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => false
        ]);
```

Comment: Please specify which plugin you have used for admin. Also  please share the code of admin App Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change**

```
'storage' => 'Session'
```

**to**

```
'storage' => [                       // Add this array
                'className' => 'Session',
                'key' => 'Auth.Admin',              
            ],
```

in your admin panel Auth cofiguration.

For e.g. Assuming below admin panel Auth configuration:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
                    'loginAction' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'],
                'logoutRedirect' => [
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'login',
                ],
                    'authenticate' => [
                        'Form' => [
                            'userModel' => 'Users',
                            'fields' => ['username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password']
                        ]
                    ],
                    'authError' => 'Enter Credentials',
                    'storage' => [              // Change this
                            'className' => 'Session',
                            'key' => 'Auth.Admin',              
                    ],
                    'unauthorizedRedirect' => false

                ]
            );
```

Comment: This is working but i cant logout anymore from admin

Comment: public function logout()

    {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

Comment: @SmitaKagwade Great! Don't forget to accept the answer. It will help the others. And keep on learning